# how to integrate app id to my existing microservice

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I have a microservice which is running in docker container, can I integrate app id into my application? and do not change the application code.
Also, I only saw google and facebook login item on the log in widget, 
how can I add IBM w3id to the widget?

can I store a username and password into appid? then clients can login using the pre-stored credential. how to implement this?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no any problem to secure your application using App ID, but you need to update the application (backend) code if you need to protect REST APIs. If you need to authenticate your mobile app users only, there is no need to change the backend code (you can review our iOS and Android onboarding samples available in the service dashboard). 
IBMid is not released to production yet, so currently there is no option to add it.
About customer credentials - we're working on Cloud Directory feature now, this scenario will be supported once we release it to production.

Thanks,
Vitaly